# Activerecord do incorrect convertion to sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm using rails 3.2.3, rspec 2.9.0, mysql5.1

The original request is

```
def index
  @votes = current_contest.votes.select('COUNT(*) AS votes_count, submission_id').group('submission_id').order('votes_count DESC')
end
```

In development env all works fine, but in my test I got error(ActiveRecord add additional aliases and rewrite mine)

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'votes_count' in 'order clause': SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, submission_id AS submission_id FROM `votes` INNER JOIN `invitations` ON `votes`.`invitation_id` = `invitations`.`id` WHERE `invitations`.`contest_id` = 1 AND (`invitations`.`status` = 'used') GROUP BY submission_id ORDER BY votes_count DESC
```

I can catch this error on a simple query like this

```
def index    
  @votes = Vote.select('COUNT(*) AS votes_count, submission_id')
end
```

log output is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `votes`
```

BUT!!! If I do

```
def index    
  @votes = Vote.select('COUNT(*) AS votes_count, submission_id')
  @votes.inspect # or something else calling @votes
end
```

I got the correct sql query in console log

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS votes_count, submission_id FROM `votes`
```

Comment: Maybe your test database is not up to date. Try running `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: I've updated question - now in happens and in dev env. Very strange behaviour as for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, you call something like

```
if @votes.any?
```

in your view.

Method `any?` will count records in the table. 
For instance, `Vote.any?` will produce something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all FROM `votes`;
```

In your case your `COUNT(*) AS votes_count` will be replaced with `COUNT(*) AS count_all`, but alias `votes_count` will be left in the order clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, submission_id AS submission_id FROM `votes` 
  INNER JOIN `invitations` ON `votes`.`invitation_id` = `invitations`.`id` 
WHERE `invitations`.`contest_id` = 1 AND (`invitations`.`status` = 'used') 
GROUP BY submission_id 
ORDER BY votes_count DESC
```

Comment: awesome! This is exactly my situation, forgot for .any? call in view